# Combine two JSONPath queries

Tags: python, jsonpath, jsonpath-ng

I need to combine the following JSONPath queries into a single query.

```
mapping_id = 1.1

jsonpath_expression = parse(f'HEADERS[*].SUB_HEADERS[?(@.HEADER_ID=={mapping_id}) & (@.HEADER_IXML_PARAID != "")].HEADER_IXML_PARAID, SECTION_TEXT_PARAID_LIST')

jsonpath_expression = parse(f'HEADERS[?(@.HEADER_ID=={mapping_id}) & (@.HEADER_IXML_PARAID != "")].HEADER_IXML_PARAID, SECTION_TEXT_PARAID_LIST')
```

Following is the JSON format that I need to get the information from:

```
{
    "HEADERS": [
        {
            "HEADER_ID": 1,
            "HEADER_NAME": "HEADING 1 TEXT",
            "HEADER_IXML_PARAID": "116BACE8",
            "SECTION_TEXT_PARAID_LIST": [],
            "SUB_HEADERS": [
                {
                    "HEADER_ID": 1.1,
                    "HEADER_NAME": "Therapeutic indications",
                    "HEADER_IXML_PARAID": "0A863DE3",
                    "SECTION_TEXT_PARAID_LIST": [
                        "4E01355B",
                        "132F90DD"
                    ],
                    "SUB_HEADERS": []
                }],
        },
        {
            "HEADER_ID": 2,
            "HEADER_NAME": "HEADING 2 TEXT",
            "HEADER_IXML_PARAID": "116BACE8",
            "SECTION_TEXT_PARAID_LIST": [],
            "SUB_HEADERS": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Right now, this is the approach that I am using, but I would prefer to combine the two.

```
from jsonpath_ng.ext import parse

jsonpath_expression = parse(f'HEADERS[?(@.HEADER_ID=={mapping_id}) & (@.HEADER_IXML_PARAID != "")].HEADER_IXML_PARAID, SECTION_TEXT_PARAID_LIST')
match = jsonpath_expression.find(self.tagged_sections)
if not match:
    jsonpath_expression = parse(f'HEADERS[*].SUB_HEADERS[?(@.HEADER_ID=={mapping_id}) & 
                                (@.HEADER_IXML_PARAID != "")].HEADER_IXML_PARAID, SECTION_TEXT_PARAID_LIST')
    match = jsonpath_expression.find(self.tagged_sections)
```

Comment: Do you have any sample data?  Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: Please see the [suggestions for good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have asked before.  What are you expecting? (Which values do you want returned?)

Comment: @gregsdennis, I need `HEADER_IXML_PARAID` and `SECTION_TEXT_PARAID_LIST` for a particular `HEADER_ID`. The particular HEADER_ID can be directly inside `HEADERS` or inside `SUB_HEADERS`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which library that you're using, but many implementations support comma-delimited keys: `['foo','bar']`.  You could use this along with a recursive descent operator: `..`.

```
$..[?(@.HEADER_ID==8.3) & (@.HEADER_IXML_PARAID != "")].HEADER_IXML_PARAID, SECTION_TEXT_PARAID_LIST
```

You also have some syntax that would be considered non-standard, though it may be supported by your library.  I would right it as

```
$..                                                        // recursive descent
  [?(@.HEADER_ID==8.3 && @.HEADER_IXML_PARAID != "")]      // item filter
  ['HEADER_IXML_PARAID', 'SECTION_TEXT_PARAID_LIST']       // prop selection
```

The last thing is what I imagine you're asking for: combining the filter expression.

```
$..
  [?(@.HEADER_ID==1 || @.HEADER_ID==8.3) && @.HEADER_IXML_PARAID != "")]
  ['HEADER_IXML_PARAID', 'SECTION_TEXT_PARAID_LIST']
```

Be aware though that this will only select `HEADER_IXML_PARAID`, and `SECTION_TEXT_PARAID_LIST` and return all of the values in a collection; it can't ensure that they remain associated with each other.